# How can I get my ajax request date format to match my database date format?

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, linq

I’ve been trying to use the date in a linq query like this:

```
 public ActionResult GetSchedule(string selectedDate)
    {

  DateTime daySearch = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedDate);
        viewModel.Assignments = from a in db.Assignments where a.teacherId == intTeacherId select a;
```

The problem is the date format in my database looks My database date looks like this

"2014-05-26 00:00:00.0000000" and my date from the ajax call looks like this...5/26/2014:12:00:00 AM.

I’ve tried a request that looks like …

```
 var allTeacherSchecules = from x in db.Assignments where x.teacherId == intTeacherId select x;

 viewModel.Assignments = from ss in allTeacherSchecules where allTeacherSchecules Contains(selectedDate) select ss;
```

...that way I won’t have to worry about specific matching but 'Contains' does not work here.
         How can I get my ajax request date format to match my database date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're approaching the problem the wrong way.  Your queries should be combined into one to leverage the capabilities of linq and the database.  Try re-writing

```
var allTeacherSchecules = from x in db.Assignments where x.teacherId == intTeacherId select x;

 viewModel.Assignments = from ss in allTeacherSchecules where allTeacherSchecules Contains(selectedDate) select ss;
```

to something like

```
viewModel.Assignments = (from x in db.Assignments 
where x.teacherId equals intTeacherId 
and x.assignmentDate equals selectedDate
select x).ToList();
```